# SaveChanges() inside foreach, to get ID inserted

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert inside a foreach and then get the ID inserted to insert this ID in another table (head and detail). And I have 2 foreach inside another. I'm using entity framework.

```
var remisiones = dbLocal.Database.SqlQuery<datosConsulta>(qDocumento).ToList();
       
foreach (var x in remisiones)
{
    var bcDoc = new bcDocumentos();
    bcDoc.cfecha = Convert.ToDateTime(x.CFECHA);
    dbLocal.bcDocumentos.Add(bcDoc);

    dbLocal.SaveChanges();

    int idBcDocumento = bcDoc.id_documento; // I NEED TO GET THIS ID INSERTED
    
    foreach (var z in movimientos)
    {
        var bcMovs = new bcMovimientos();
        bcMovs.id_documento = idBcDocumento; // TO INSERT HERE IN THE DETAIL TABLE
        dbLocal.bcMovimientos.Add(bcMovs);

        dbLocal.SaveChanges();

        int idBcMovimiento = bcMovs.id_movimiento; // AND THEN GET THE NEW ID FO THE DETAIL
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks like it should work? Are you certain that the database column for id_documento is configured as an IDENTITY(1,1) column (or similar?). Also are you using code-first EF or database-first EF? You might need to refresh EF in the code if it's unaware that id_documento is an IDENTITY column and gets a new value upon saving. Or if code-first, you might need to add this attribute to that property: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Looks like you're not using navigation properties to build the entire object tree first and then save it in one `SaveChanges` call, in which EF will set the generated key values "just in time".

Comment: After insert the record in db I get the right next ID. @ryancdotnet like I have the code

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is about. The code you have posted is an extremely inefficient way to go about it, but it should give you the IDs, however the idBcMovimiento will only exist within the scope of that `foreach` block so that is where any further code that needs that ID and the outer row's ID will be able to access them. The correct approach is to leverage navigation properties for the related entities and leave it to EF to resolve and insert the appropriate FKs on a single `SaveChanges` call to ensure the related data is saved together or not at all if any of it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified the `id_documento` field in the database as `Identity`, you can use the following code, otherwise change id_documento to Identity.

```
int idBcDocumento = dbLocal.bcDocumentos.OrderByDescending(p => p.id_documento).First().id_documento;
```

full code

```
var remisiones = dbLocal.Database.SqlQuery<datosConsulta>(qDocumento).ToList();
       
foreach (var x in remisiones)
{
    var bcDoc = new bcDocumentos();
    bcDoc.cfecha = Convert.ToDateTime(x.CFECHA);
    dbLocal.bcDocumentos.Add(bcDoc);

    dbLocal.SaveChanges();

    int idBcDocumento = dbLocal.bcDocumentos.OrderByDescending(p => p.id_documento).First().id_documento; // I NEED TO GET THIS ID INSERTED
    
    foreach (var z in movimientos)
    {
        var bcMovs = new bcMovimientos();
        bcMovs.id_documento = idBcDocumento; // TO INSERT HERE IN THE DETAIL TABLE
        dbLocal.bcMovimientos.Add(bcMovs);

        dbLocal.SaveChanges();

        int idBcMovimiento = dbLocal.bcMovs.OrderByDescending(p => p.id_movimiento).First().id_movimiento; // AND THEN GET THE NEW ID FO THE DETAIL
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. When I insert the record, I can get the ID. The problem is down. When I need to insert in the other table, the ID that I get (this table is used for details), and the main table I use for the head

Comment: I don't know if the problem is the Foreach inside another and It can´t works

Comment: I put the complete code. If you run your code and see what error messages.